# CSS Replace black bars from YouTube embed

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm trying to put a YouTube video as a background to the slider. As it sits, the video is in the perfect location. I just want to get put an image where the black bars are: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjvlxamvjqtyx54/Screenshot%202015-08-18%2012.05.53.png?dl=0`

Here is my code:

```
<div id="slide_0" class="slide-content">
          <div class="slide-bg" style="background: url('/assets/images/pages/home/home-background.jpg') center top no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
            <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6MWYmtT6bvc?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-footer">
            <table>
              <tr class="middle">
                <td>
                  <center>
                  </center>
                  <img class="logo" id="slider-logo" src="/assets/images/pages/home/heading-1.png" alt="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="bottom">
                <td>
                  <div class="slide-caption">
                      <div class="content">
                            <span class="caption"><img class="globe" src="/assets/images/pages/home/globe1.png" alt="">Ray caters for international appointments and makes regular visits to Moscow, New York, The Middle East and most European Cities, stay tuned for the dates of his next trip.</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would like the background image (line 2) to be a background to the video.

Notice how I'm using height="100%" and width="100%". On removing the width attribute, I'm left with: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/pq2t4basz4lhf8a/Screenshot%202015-08-18%2012.09.03.png?dl=0`

If you can help that would be great,
Thanks!
Toby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do so unless you know the video aspect ratio. The reason of that is that you load a new page in the `<iframe>` which content is immutable.

If you know the aspect ratio and it is constant (let's say 16:9) you can calculate the width based on height with pure CSS:

```
width: calc(your_height * 16 / 9);
```

Then align it to the center and this will work.

If the ratio is known but it is dynamic you can do the same but with JavaScript.

If it is unknown - you cannot do anything.

**Another way:**

maybe this way is not working for you but is still worth mentioning it. Display the video image instead of youtube video, e.g. like this http://img.youtube.com/vi/EqWRZrupLrI/0.jpg . This will allow you to make a background around this image with usual `background-size: contain` for the youtube image. When user clicks on the image you can replace it with a video and autoplay enabled. When this happens the background will of course not be visible anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done.
The black padding you get around the video is part of the player and sits on the same "layer" as the video itself. Youtube puts that to fill extra space around the video so they can maintain the aspect ratio of the video while still be able to fit the player to the requested size (the `width` & `height` parameters).

Comment: How can I manually set the aspect ratio to where there is no black bars? Then I can underlay this with the background image.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. You can put the width & height of the PLAYER. The video inside it will maintain its original aspect ratio inside those boundaries (the player dimensions), and the black padding will fill the "empty" space between the video and the player. Notice that if you change the player size, the black area size & position changes accordingly, while the video aspect ratio remains.